# code execution after Springboot Embedded Tomcat is completly started

Tags: spring-boot

I want to execute a code when springboot embedded tomcat is completely started. I have tried with Spring Event handlers such as Context refreshed event. But It is being executed before tomcat starts up. I dont want tomcat to be interrupted when my code execution fails. Appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Boot 2 or later, you can listen for the `org.springframework.boot.web.context.WebServerInitializedEvent` event. It is published once the application context has been refreshed and Tomcat is listening for HTTP requests. If you're still using Spring Boot 1.5, the equivalent event is `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent`

Comment: But, when i deploy the war to external tomcat with this event(WebServerInitializedEvent), it did not work. Could you tell me the reason for this.

Comment: The event is published as part of Spring Boot starting the embedded Tomcat instance. If you're deploying to an external container, there's no embedded container to start and, therefore, no event is published.

Comment: Is there anyway to get this worked with external tomcat.